# How do I create an unbound method for new in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, function-pointers

I have this code:

```
class Note < Struct.new :value
  def to_s
    value.to_s
  end
  def self.use_new(arg)
    Note.new arg
  end
end

class Chord
  def initialize(arr)
    @arr = arr
  end

  def play
    @arr.join('-')
  end
end
new_method = Note.singleton_method(:use_new)
chords = %w{ G Bb Dd E }
c = Chord.new(chords.map(:new_method))
puts c.play
```

Now I know I don't have to do this with map, I can simply use `map {|n| Note.new n}`

But I want to know how to do this. The following says Note doesn't have a method called singleton_method. When I try and use instance method (without the self in the definition) it says the method doesn't exist. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want an `UnboundMethod`? There's not much you can sensibly do with an `UnboundMethod`. In particular, you cannot `call` it. The only thing you can do is `bind` it to an instance of the `module` you got it from in order to obtain a bound `Method`. In this case, however, the `module` in question is `Note`'s singleton class which has only one instance anyway, so you can only `bind` it to `Note`. So, you might just as well get a bound `Method` in the first place:

```
new_method = Note.method(:use_new)
chords = %w{ G Bb Dd E }
c = Chord.new(chords.map(&new_method)) # BTW: you had a typo here
puts c.play
```

I also don't understand what the purpose of your `Note::use_new` is. It is simply a no-op wrapper around `Note::new`, so it might just as well be an `alias_method` instead. Or, even better, just remove it, it doesn't server any purpose:

```
new_method = Note.method(:new)
chords = %w{ G Bb Dd E }
c = Chord.new(chords.map(&new_method)) # BTW: you had a typo here
puts c.play
```

You can use `singleton_method` as well, if you want to make sure to *only* get singleton methods:

```
new_method = Note.singleton_method(:use_new)
chords = %w{ G Bb Dd E }
c = Chord.new(chords.map(&new_method)) # BTW: you had a typo here
puts c.play
```

If you *really* insist on getting an `UnboundMethod`, then you will have to `bind` it first, before you can use it, and you have to get it from the singleton class, since `singleton_method` returns a `Method` not an `UnboundMethod`:

```
new_method = Note.singleton_class.instance_method(:use_new)
chords = %w{ G Bb Dd E }
c = Chord.new(chords.map(&new_method.bind(Note)))
puts c.play
```

Comment: I didn't really understand how to do this. I tried to grab new, but thought it was "ungrabbable" so I defined a method to grab it for me. I didn't know we could use #method on a class. I thought it always had to be instance_method or singleton_method. When I first tried to use singleton_method it said that function was undefined for class Note. I've been trying to understand this kind of thing for a long time now. Why do I have to use & in map? I thought & was the equivilant of calling method.to_proc, can't I just pass the method? How do I know what .to_proc yields?

Comment: I don't suppose you'd have time to confirm this as well would you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824244/understanding-ruby-metaprogramming-using-method-added-to-overwrite-instance-meth 

Thanks for all your help Jorg.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
new_method = (class << Note; self; end).instance_method(:use_new)
```

This fixes the main problem, though there are still some others.

Comment: Ahh, this is the workaround to get the self for the singleton class right? Is this really the only way to do this properly?

Comment: @Senjai: Pretty much, yeah.

Comment: Actually this doesnt work. i've tried playing around with it. Put it wont work in map

Comment: @Senjai: it answers your question though it doesn't fix the code.